# Cursor disappears using Dual Monitors over windows set to Always Visible

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, mouse

I use a laptop, so I don't always have two displays. My mouse disappears when I have both monitors displaying and a window in "Always Visible" mode on the built-in laptop display. Often, this occurs when I am typing within Text Editor, which is normal; what isn't normal is that getting the mouse to re-appear takes about a second of shaking the mouse. Performance is better if I turn off "Always Visible" on the window. I believe I have similar problems in full-screen mode.

Please let me know any additional information that might be helpful to look into this. I have looked at several other solutions on AskUbuntu, so I'll add specifics related to those. First, the cursor disappears occasionally, not permanently and reappears after shaking the mouse. I don't have any additional displays listed in settings besides the two displays that I'm using.